# What is the approach to "reload" Flux sink on different requests?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm quite new to Flux approach, so please pardon me if I articulate the details little wrong.
I have created a sink to be used as a stream response:

```
@Configuration
class SinkConfig {

    @Bean
    fun sink(): Sinks.Many<Notification> {
        return Sinks.many().multicast().directAllOrNothing()
    }

    @Bean
    fun broadcast(
        sink: Sinks.Many<Notification>
    ): Flux<Notification> {
        return sink.asFlux()
    }
}
```

Then I provide this sink as flux directly to controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
class ProcessingController(
    private val processingFlux: Flux<Notification>,
) {

    @GetMapping("/processing", produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE])
    fun processing(): Flux<Notification> {

        // some business logig goes here
        // ...

        return processingFlux
    }
}
```

So, basically I keep stream open and emit some data there when I get it from other sources. Internally I produce and consume spring events like that:

```
@Service
class WebSocketGateway(
    private val processingSink: Sinks.Many<Notification>,
) {

    @EventListener(WebSocketEvent::class)
    fun handleEvent(event: WebSocketEvent) {

        when (event.message) {
            
            // Other event types
            // ...

            is AddTranscript -> {

                // Here emit broadcast events
                processingSink.tryEmitNext(Notification())
            }

            is EndOfTranscript -> {

                // Here I emit the completion
                processingSink.tryEmitComplete()
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that when I emit `tryEmitComplete()` - my flux becomes completed and unavailable for other client requests :)
And the problem about it is that I need to complete client's stream and send him 200 (Ok) response. I don't see any reason to keep it opened. But as far as I depend on sink I can't do that.

Regarding this I have few questions.

1. Is this the right approach to have a single sink for multicast? It seems problematic if I need to handle a lot of data by different domain entities. For example, if I process different files, should I have the same flux sink for all of then or a single per file?
2. Is there any way to gracefully complete client's stream but keep the original sink flux? (Because it could be used for other connections).
3. Is it okay to create some kind of flux factory and create a new sink & flux for any incoming request?
4. Is there any other approach to deal with this flux? It seems strange to depend from a single flux.